# Integration tests stuck at starting when run from a bash script

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I am running an issue where integration tests work as expected in one instance and are stuck in a starting state in another instance. Below are the 2 docker files and the script file.

The working docker file has the entrypoint set to run the dotnet test command. The problematic docket file has the entrypoint set to a script file that simply sleeps for 10 seconds and runs the dotnet test command.

When I run the problematic docker file (the one with the script), test execution kicks off but is stuck at starting. No matter how long I wait it is stuck in a starting state. The output states test file found, discovered tests, and starting execution but remains as such until I stop the container.

The working docker file runs to completion in 30 seconds or so. Note I run everything through a compose file. I am unsure why the tests hang when the dotnet test command is run through a script file. I can run it locally without docker with no issues, I can run it in docker with the entrypoint set to the dotnet test command, but cannot solve how to run it through a script file.

**Working docker file**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:latest AS build
WORKDIR /src
#copy relevant project files, run dot net restore and copy everything else
#note I removed a large portion of the docker file here which is  just copying .csproj files

RUN chmod +x startup.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "test", "--verbosity=normal", "--logger:trx;LogFileName=integration_tests.trx", "--results-directory:/results/integration"]
```

**Stuck docker file**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:latest AS build
WORKDIR /src
#copy relevant project files, run dot net restore and copy everything else
#note I removed a large portion of the docker file here which is  just copying .csproj files

RUN chmod +x startup.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/src/startup.sh"]
```

**startup.sh - bash file**

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 10

echo "Slept 10 seconds - executing command"
dotnet test --verbosity "normal" --logger "trx;LogFileName=integration_tests.trx" --results-directory "/results/integration"
```

**Compose file**

```
version: '3.4'

# docker ports host:container (80:8080 maps 80 on host to 8080 in container)
services:
  integration.test:
    image: integrationtest
    container_name: integrationtest
    build:
    #context is relative to location of compose file
      context: .
      dockerfile: src\Dockerfile
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - MassTransit:Host=rabbitmq
      - MassTransit:ImageDeletedEndpoint=rabbitmq://rabbitmq/ImageDeleted
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/tests:/results
    depends_on:
      - test.viewdb
      - rabbitmq

  test.viewdb:
    image: ravendb/ravendb:ubuntu-latest
    container_name: testviewdb
    environment:
      - RAVEN_Setup_Mode=None 
      - RAVEN_License_Eula_Accepted=true
      - RAVEN_Security_UnsecuredAccessAllowed=PrivateNetwork
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "38888:38888"
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/config:/opt/RavenDB/config
      - ./volumes/data:/opt/RavenDB/Server/RavenData

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:management
    hostname: rabbitmq
    container_name: rabbitmq
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE='secretcookiehere' 
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=broker
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=password
    expose:
      - "15672"
      - "5672"
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/rabbitmq:/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/
```

Comment: One difference is that the script is executing `dotnet` in a subshell that's not (?) inheriting the environment from the container's shell.

Comment: Have you checked the container's logs? (`docker-compose logs integratontest`)

Comment: I think you shoudn't use sleep in your entrypoints try using healthcheck in docker-compose to wait for rabbitmq and ravendb to be up before start the integration test container. Example for rabbitmq: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/12092/docker-compose-healthcheck-for-rabbitmq

Comment: @DazWilkin Yup I checked the logs and it starts up the integration tests but hangs. So it's definitely finding the project, the integration test file, and executing it. I see an output for starting tests but even a single test is not run to completion. It gets permanently stuck in the starting state

Comment: @nivhty I'll try that out instead of sleep in entrypoint and verify if it resolves the issue